# jQuery cannot access parent of dynamically created element - parent is undefined

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm making login and registration forms in which data is send through ajax calls. Server side is made with flask and errors are returned in json format. Then, in ajax success function I add `<li>` element with error information and close (×) button, and slide down the `ul`. Like this:

```
 if ('email' in response) {
               $('#email-error').append('<li class="w3-display-container w3-red w3-round">' + response['email'] + '<span class="w3-button w3-circle w3-display-right">&times;</span></li>');
               $('#email-error').slideDown(250);
           }
```

It works fine. Problem is, I can't close these notifications. Since there are multiple notifications and they're added dynamically, I've got a callback function to detect whether the button was pressed:

```
$(document).on('click', '.w3-button.w3-circle.w3-display-right', function () {
    $(this).parent.hide();
});
```

This sort of works - button click is detected, `$(this)` returns right button ( `$(this).hide()` makes the button disappear). But I need to hide the `<ul>` ( or at least `<li>` ) elements. I tried referring to their parent elements, but `$(this).parent` returns undefined (that's what console.log said). Also, error notifications aren't visible when viewing page source. How can I get to those lists and close them?

Comment: Typo.  It should be `parent()`.  It's a method

Comment: `parentNode` is vanilla JS, `parent()` is jQuery.

Comment: Thank you!
So much headache because of a typo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this).parent is wrong. use parent() method

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $('ul').append('<li class="w3-display-container w3-red w3-round">response <span class="w3-button w3-circle w3-display-right">&times;</span></li>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.w3-button.w3-circle.w3-display-right', function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>add</button>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: There is a close reason specific for typos.